# How can I use Already downloaded images from cache with Universal Image Loader

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I used Universal Image Loader to fetch the Data from uri in let say `Activity A`, but I don't to use the `displayImage()` method to fetch the images from uri again at `Activity B`.

Instead I want to fetch the images already stored in cache to another `Activity B`

How can this be done?

I have used these options to initialize the Image Loader

```
DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheOnDisc(true).cacheInMemory(true)
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                .displayer(new FadeInBitmapDisplayer(300)).build();

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(
                getApplicationContext())
                .defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions)
                .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
                .discCacheSize(100 * 1024 * 1024).build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
```

and then called this to get the Image

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

//download and display image from url
imageLoader.displayImage(url, myImageView);
```

Comment: if image url is already downloaded then your universal image loader library show the image from the cached images only no need to get that image untill you need to perfrom somthing else without just showing

Comment: So in activity B, I have to call the same method `loadImage()` to get the previously cached Image?

Comment: Yes it is You already stroring images to cach

Comment: You can test this first time load all the images from online after loading just turn off the internet and check again it will show your images


Let me know if still issue are there

Comment: let me know what you got ?

Comment: Yes it's working in Activity B, but it is making unwanted connections to download the image when the internet is not connected, Every time the 'getView()' method is called in ListView when scrolling.

'failed to connect to /192.168.1.3 (port 80) after 5000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)
                                                                                 java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.3 (port 80) after 5000ms: connect failed: ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution to :

> Yes it's working in Activity B, but it is making unwanted connections
>   to download the image when the internet is not connected, Every time
>   the 'getView()' method is called in ListView when scrolling. 'failed
>   to connect to /192.168.1.3 (port 80) after 5000ms: connect failed:
>   ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable) java.net.ConnectException: failed
>   to connect to /192.168.1.3 (port 80) after 5000ms: connect failed:
>   ENETUNREACH (Network is unreachable)`

```
  ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

        File file = imageLoader.getDiskCache().get(image_url);
        if (file==null) {

            //Load image from network
        }
        else {
           //Load image from cache
            mImageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(file.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
```